# How to show Min and Max value on dynamic pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I created a pivot table from dt_table join with dt_k

```
table dt_k
+------+--------+-----+
| id_k | name_k | ott |
+------+--------+-----+
|  1   | item 1 | ss  |
|  2   | item 2 | ss  |
|  3   | item 3 | ww  |
|  4   | item 4 | dd  |
|  5   | item 5 | asa |
|  6   | item 6 | rr  |
+------+--------+-----+

dt_table
+------+--------+------+----+
| id_t |  id_u  | id_k | k  |
+------+--------+------+----+
|  1   |   22   |  1   | 2  |
|  2   |   22   |  2   | 3  |
|  3   |   22   |  3   | 23 |
|  4   |   22   |  4   | 4  |
|  5   |   22   |  6   | 34 |
|  6   |   24   |  1   | 23 |
|  7   |   24   |  2   | 34 |
|  8   |   24   |  3   | 54 |
|  9   |   24   |  4   | 21 |
| 11   |   24   |  6   | 44 |
+------+--------+------+----+
```

I am use pivot table to convert row to column this my code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'max(case when col = ''',
  col,
  ''' then value end) as `', 
  col, '`')
) INTO @sql
FROM
(
select concat('op_', `id_k`) col
from dt_table

) d;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  d.id_u as id,', @sql, ' 
              from
              (
                select id_k, id_u, concat(''op_'', `id_k`) col,  k value
                from dt_table

              ) d group by id_u ');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

this code gives a result like following

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id_u | op_1 | op_2 | op_3 | op_4 | op_6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  22  |   2  |  3   |  23  |  4   |  34' |
|  24  |  23  |  34  |  54  |  21  |  44  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I need this table show min and max value on each column like this

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id_u | op_1 | op_2 | op_3 | op_4 | op_6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  22  |   2  |  3   |  23  |  4   |  34  |
|  24  |  23  |  34  |  54  |  21  |  44  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+

+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id_u | op_1 | op_2 | op_3 | op_4 | op_6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| min  |   2  |  3   |  23  |  4   |  34  |
| max  |  23  |  34  |  54  |  21  |  44  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Thanks for your help..
This resource for recent work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/297674/1

Comment: What do you do with this result ?

Comment: thanks for response, I want to calculate the distance each row with the maximum  or minimum value

Comment: And you simply want to display this on the command line?

Comment: no i want the final table is display the distance of each row,

Comment: For the 3rd time of asking... Where? In a book? A film? A magazine? A web page somewhere?

Comment: on webpage with php page

Comment: Actually, I still have no idea what 'min' and 'max' mean in this context. 22 always holds the 'min' value, right?

Answer (score 0):

What part of the problem does the following fail to solve?

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/statme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT id_u
     , id_k
     , k
  FROM dt_table
 ORDER 
    BY id_u
     , id_k;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $v){
  $new_array[$v['id_u']][] = $v['k'];
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```