# Dynamically generate Columns via sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, multiple-columns, dynamically-generated

i have appoitment table with following columns

```
(Id_patient,date_appointment,time_appoitment)
Exp
14,29/12/2019,09:10
19,30/12/2019,11:30
```

I want to create an sql query that generate result like that , I sélect date between 29/12/2019 and 01/01/2020  and 
Time_appointment between 08:00 and 23:00

```
Time_appoitment,29/12/2019,30/12/2109,31/12/2019,01/01/2020
08:00.         ,Null      ,null      ,Null      ,Null
.
.
09:10          ,14        ,Null      ,Null      ,Null
.
.
11:30          ,Null      ,19        ,Null      ,Null

.

.
23:00          ,Null     ,Null       ,Null      ,Null
```

Comment: Consider storing dates and times as a single entity, using an appropriate data type, and then handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Strawberry , thanks, but can you please details your answer.

Comment: As a rule, the `mysql` and `tsql` tags are incompatible (as their description state). Do you require a solution that works in both? It's curious that appointments have no duration, i.e. a 10 minute oil change vs. an 18 hour surgery. What have you tried? What research have you done? Did it involve a _tally_ (or _numbers_) table and an `outer join`? Perhaps a `pivot`? Can you provide DDL for your table?

Comment: Time_appointment = time_start and it incrément for 10 min

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041578/how-to-show-min-and-max-value-on-dynamic-pivot-table/37045184#37045184

Answer (score 0):

Markus Winand details this answer well on this post: [Pivot Rows to Columns](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot)

Paragraph to note:
SQL is a statically typed language: the query must list the result columns upfront. To pivot a table with unknown or dynamic attributes, multisets or document types (XML, JSON) can be used to represent a key-value store in a single column. See conforming alternatives to listagg: document types.

Basically, what you are asking is not something SQL (as a standard) is designed to do. There are, however, one off solutions in some RDBMS systems which would meet your needs. Would suggest you read up on your flavor of database's documentation on PIVOT, CROSSTAB, or something of that sort.